# How to have a delay effect on hover delegation in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use jquery event delegation technique for hover events. But I only want the hover code to trigger after a second of hovering on. So far I have this:

```
        $('body').on('mouseenter', "a", function( event ) {

            var interval = setTimeout(function() {  


            }, 1000);   

        }).on('mouseleave', "a", function( event ) {


        });
```

Which delays the function by a second, but what I don't get is how to cancel the timeout if the user moves the mouse out. I know there is `clearTimeout` but I don't know how to use it, like how do I get the interval number for the correct `a` tag.

And we can't assume that the `a` will have any relevant attribute like `name` or `id`.

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `clearTimeout`:

```
    $('body').on('mouseenter', "a", function( event ) {
        if( this.interval ) 
           clearTimeout(this.interval);
        this.interval = setTimeout(function() {  


        }, 1000);   
    }).on('mouseleave', "a", function( event ) {
       clearTimeout(this.interval);
       this.interval = null;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way without needing any external variables would be store the timerId on the element itself using `data()`

```
 $('body').on('mouseenter', "a", function(event) {

    var interval = setTimeout(function() {
      // do some stuff
    }, 1000);
    $(this).data('interval', interval)

  }).on('mouseleave', "a", function(event) {    
      clearTimeout($(this).data('interval'));
  });
```

Comment: Use of `this.interval =` is better in this case.

Comment: @c-smile yeah..probably would be

Comment: Not "would" but definitely "is".  Timer id can be non-serializeable to string. E.g. private symbol for example. Or object reference.

Comment: @c-smile data() doesn't serialize when setting. Not the same as using attributes

Comment: If there is a guarantee that "data() doesn't serialize" then yes.

Comment: @c-smile Take a look here https://jsfiddle.net/87zvk0fg/ Can see an `===` object reference comparison

Comment: @c-smile also very common for jQuery plugins to store everything from plugin state to even methods using `data()`

Comment: For jQuery plugins it is better to store data in closures  ( if that's private data )

Comment: @c-smile Still boils down to different strokes/different folks. Still a common pattern. [Fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) is an example of a heavily used plugin that uses it. Run `console.table($('#calendar').data('fullCalendar'))`  on any instance such as on their main page....will see huge object with methods, state and even some internals

Answer (score 0):

You can save the id generated from `setTimeout` and pass it to `clearTimeout`:

```
var interval; // declare interval here

$('body').on('mouseenter', "a", function( event ) {

  interval = setTimeout(function() { }

}).on('mouseleave', "a", function( event ) {

  clearTimeout(interval);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

right the answers talking about clearTimeout are correct, just remember to use this.interval instead of var...to preserve context. It' also easier than using that data way:

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', "a", function( event ) {
  this.interval = setTimeout(function() {  
    // do something
  }, 1000);   
}).on('mouseleave', "a", function( event ) {
  // undo something
  clearTimeout(this.interval);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the timout (created inside the **mouseenter** handler) inside the **mouseleave** handler.

A tiny plugin to get hover delay using $.on() delegation :

```
$.fn.softHover = function(onEnter, onLeave, delay = 500){
    return this.each(function(){
        var target = this;
        var timer = setTimeout(function(){ onEnter.call( $(target) ) }, delay);
        $(target).mouseleave(function(){
            onLeave.call(this);
            clearTimeout(timer);                
        });     
    });
}
```

Just use it that way :

```
$('.page').on('mouseenter','.element',function(){
    $(this).softHover(
        function(){...}, 
        function(){...},
    );
});
```